# can't get to admin page after factory reset netgear wg602

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, reset

I have wireless Netgear wg602 on my home network (connected to my internet modem/router).

I've had it secured and locked down to only accept connection from specific MAC addresses.

I've forgotten the password that I used but my Mac Book laptops can still connect (multiple OS updates - it can't retrieve and display the password but it can use it to log in to WPA) so I want to reconfigure it from scratch (have some new devices).

I tried to reset the Netgear wg602 to factory settings (pressed reset button for 10 sec), reset my laptop IP address to local address suggested in manual (192.168.0.210 net mask 255.255.255.0), connect Netgear via ethernet cable to my mac book pro but I can't get to the admin page at 192.168.0.227 as suggested by manual (firefox or safari). At this stage the Netgear is not connected to router, it is only connected to mac book.

I can't ping the wireless access point either (but it is on all lights are on).

What am I doing incorrectly?

Last time I configured it via Windows now I only have Mac Book (which I've used with the wireless access point for 2 years so no compatibility problems).

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. After re-reading the question I decided I was totally on the wrong track.

FWIW, if you're curious whether the WG602 is using another IP than what you expect, you could try scanning a range of IP's to see if any of them "work".

[Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org) can be used on a Mac. I don't know how it compares to other IP and port scanners, but it is relatively easy to scan a range of IPs using it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/wg602_users_guide.pdf) and a couple other places it will only get the 192.168.0.227 address if DHCP isn't available.

> AP IP Address: 192.168.0.227 if DHCP is
>   disabled

If your router is handing out DHCP, and it was connected to it when you reset, it probably got an IP via DHCP.

Perhaps hook it back up to the router and check the router's interface to see what IP it was given?

Comment: I reset it couple of times when it wasn't hooked up to router, but I'll probably try reset when connected to router.